# Need to write a query in mysql to find the following

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with structure like the one shown below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS list (
    `LastName` VARCHAR(13) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `FirstName` VARCHAR(14) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `Grade` INT,
    `Classroom` INT
);
```

Here is what I am trying to find - Find all pairs of classrooms with the same number of students in them.
Report each pair only once. Report both classrooms and the number
of students.

I tried the following script

```
select classroom,count(*) as cnt
from list
group by classroom
having count(*) in (select c.cnt as v
                    from
                    (select classroom,count(*) as cnt
                     from list
                     group by classroom)c
                    group by c.cnt
                    having count(classroom) =2);
```

which yields no result.

Appreciate any help on the item above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use CTEs:

```
with c as (
      select classroom, count(*) as cnt
      from list
      group by classroom
     )
select c1.classroom, c2.classroom
from c c1 join
     c c2
     on c1.cnt = c2.cnt and c1.classroom < c2.classroom;
```

I think you are misinterpreting the question.  It is looking for a result set with *two* classrooms in each row, not a classroom with a count.

Comment: Is there an advantage to CTE's as compared to inline views? Just wondered.

Comment: @dcp . . . You only need to express the logic once.  That seems like a big advantage -- one that prevents errors by having inconsistent queries.  From a performance perspective, I am guessing the CTE would be materialized and only generated once, which would be a performance gain.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
select a.classroom, b.classroom, a.cnt
from (
  select classroom, count(*) as cnt from list group by classroom
) a
join (
  select classroom, count(*) as cnt from list group by classroom
) b on a.cnt = b.cnt and a.classroom < b.classroom
```